# Zend, MULTIPLE layouts with COMMON base code

Tags: zend-framework, layout

I know how to use multiple layouts (per Controllers and per Modules).

I have 5 diffirent layouts and they switch fine every time I call diffirent module. But the problem is I see they all have SOME portion of common code (like doctype, stylesheets etc.)

Will you tell me if Zend allows using multiple layouts but setting the common root for them? Now if i want to add stylesheet I need to modify 5 diffirent layouts what I belive could be done in a better manner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a wrapper layout that renders the content with sublayouts.

1. create a new folder in layouts called sublayouts
2. create as many sublayouts as you need with one default so you don't have to set it if you don't need to.

   /application
     /layouts
       wrapper.phtml
       /sublayouts
         default.phtml

In wrapper.phtml:

```
$sublayout = $this->layout()->sublayout ? $this->layout()->sublayout : 'default';
echo $this->render('sublayouts/' . $sublayout . '.phtml');
```

In sublayouts/default.phtml (add anything):

```
<?= $this->layout()->content ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! But where to set the SUBLAYOUT variable from? Wrapping layouts is exactly the solution that I am looking for. Now I only need to show the proper sublayout in respect to the module name. Will you help? Just to tell you, now the selection of proper layout takes place in preDispatch function from my own Application_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout.

Comment: also, to clarify, you can fetch the module name from the request (which is passed to your preDispatch function): $request->getParam('module');

Answer (score 0):

There are view helpers that are used for these situations.
[headScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript) and [headLink](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headlink).

In your layouts all you need to do is

```
echo $this->headScript(), $this->headStyle();
```

Then, in your bootstrap add:

```
public function _initScriptsAndStyles()
{
  //get the view object
  $this->bootstrap('view');
  $view = $this->getResource('view');

  //add javascript
  $view->headScript()
       ->appendFile('/js/your-js.js')
       ->appendFile('/js/another-js.js');

  //add css files
  $view->headLink()
       ->appendStylesheet('/styles/basic.css');
}
```

Comment: Sorry. It is not a correct way to put that in bootstrap while working with modules. It doesn't help a bit. I need to have this code written in 5 diffirent bootstraps which is not a good manner again. Any suggesions?

Comment: You would place this in your application/bootstrap.php file. This will be loaded in every request, regardless of module. In module bootstraps you can do the same and add additional javascript/style-sheets. This is the most dynamic approach. If every template is including the same header details (title, meta description, js, css, etc), then perhaps using a view partial? Place a .phtml file in a partials view folder (I name mine _partials), then in your different templates `echo $this->partial('_partials/header.phtml', 'default', $this);`. It is a bit like in Wordpress using `get_header();`

Comment: Oh, the above echo specifies the _partial folder to be in the default module: `Application/modules/default/views/scripts/_partials/header.phtml`